# Multiple edges between nodes using neato

Tags: graphviz, neato

I'm using neato to output a graph, which works nicely.  But neato merges edges between the same node pairs, and now I need to display multiple edges (arcs) with different properties (color, weight, possibly length) - is this possible?

I've tried to experiment with strict, splines=true/false, and different edge id and color, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to simply define multiple edges? For example,

```
graph G {
  A -- B;
  A -- B;
}
```

produces

[image: Undirected graph with two egdes between A and B]

Comment: Yes.  I made a silly mistake, and this works as advertised.  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem any way to remove a question, or vote it down, or anything.

Comment: @Ketil, you should be able to delete your own question.  If not, flag it for moderator attention with a comment that you want it to be deleted.

Comment: Also make sure you don't have the `strict` keyword before `graph`. This took me a while.